# Angular2 SPA (REST API) basic get (CRUD)

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, angular, typescript, crud

Good Morning,

I have my back-end working beautifully but just can’t finish off the front!

I'm confident in my ability to config the back however when I load my desired page I just can’t display my data.

Would someone please advise or direct to a tutorial?

This is what I'm currently using to assist: [Angular-2-crud](https://chsakell.com/2016/06/27/angular-2-crud-modals-animations-pagination-datetimepicker/)

Thanks GWS

**cashmovement-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Output, trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { DataService } from '../shared/services/data.service';
import { DateFormatPipe } from '../shared/pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { ItemsService } from '../shared/utils/items.service';
import { NotificationService } from '../shared/utils/notification.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../shared/utils/config.service';
import { ICashMovement, Pagination, PaginatedResult } from '../shared/interfaces';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'cashmovements',
templateUrl: 'cashmovement-list.component.html'
})

export class CashMovementListComponent implements OnInit { 
    public cashmovements: ICashMovement[];

constructor(private dataService: DataService,
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService) { }


ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getCashMovements()
        .subscribe((cashmovements: ICashMovement[]) => {
            this.cashmovements = cashmovements;
        },
        error => {
            this.notificationService.printErrorMessage('Failed to load users. ' + error);
        });
} 

}
```

**cashmovement-list.component.html**

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngIf="cashmovements">
   <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> CashMovements  
   <span class="badge">{{totalItems}}</span>
</button>
 
<hr/>
 
<div [@flyInOut]="'in'">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><i class="fa fa-text-width fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cash Movement ID</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>PortfolioCode</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-paragraph fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>CCY Out</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Account Out</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let cashmovement of cashmovements">
                <td> {{cashmovement.CashMovementId}}</td>
                <td>{{cashmovement.PortfolioCode}}</td>
                <td>{{cashmovement.Ccyo}}</td>
                <td>{{cashmovement.AccountO}}</td>
                <td>{{cashmovement.Date | dateFormat | date:'medium'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

**interfaces.ts**

```
export interface ICashMovement {
 CashMovementId: number;
 PortfolioCode: string;
 Date: Date;
 Ccyo: string;     
 AccountO: string;
 ValueO: number;
 Ccyi: string;     
 AccountI: string;
 ValueI: number;
 status: string;
 comment: string;
 LastUpdate: number;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import './rxjs-operators';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { SlimLoadingBarService, SlimLoadingBarComponent } from 'ng2-slim-    loading-bar';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DateFormatPipe } from './shared/pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { HighlightDirective } from   './shared/directives/highlight.directive';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MobileHideDirective } from './shared/directives/mobile-hide.directive';

import { CashMovementListComponent } from './cashmovements/cashmovement-list.component';

import { routing } from './app.routes';


import { DataService } from './shared/services/data.service';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/utils/config.service';
import { ItemsService } from './shared/utils/items.service';
import { MappingService } from './shared/utils/mapping.service';
import { NotificationService } from './shared/utils/notification.service';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2BootstrapModule,
    ModalModule,
    ProgressbarModule,
    PaginationModule,
    routing,
    TimepickerModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DateFormatPipe,
    HighlightDirective,
    HomeComponent,
    MobileHideDirective,
    SlimLoadingBarComponent,
    CashMovementListComponent        
],
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    DataService,
    ItemsService,
    MappingService,
    NotificationService,
    SlimLoadingBarService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { ICashMovement, Pagination, PaginatedResult } from '../interfaces';
import { ItemsService } from '../utils/items.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../utils/config.service';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    _baseUrl: string = '';

    constructor(private http: Http,
        private itemsService: ItemsService,
        private configService: ConfigService) {
        this._baseUrl = configService.getApiURI();
    }


    getCashMovements(): Observable<ICashMovement[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._baseUrl + 'cashmovements')
            .map((res: Response) => { return res.json();     })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        var applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
        var serverError = error.json();
        var modelStateErrors: string = '';

        if (!serverError.type) {
            console.log(serverError);
            for (var key in serverError) {
                if (serverError[key])
                    modelStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
            }
        }

        modelStateErrors = modelStateErrors = '' ? null : modelStateErrors;

        return Observable.throw(applicationError || modelStateErrors || 'Server error');
    }


}
```

Comment: You are not seeing anything? What kind of output do you get? Do you get the table with at least the `th`?

Comment: Hi Husein, The page is loading with headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your `templateUrl`. You need to prefix the partial view with `./` regardless of whether you use `moduleId`.  You need to specify `templateUrl: "./cashmovement-list.component.html"`

However, if you are getting any error in the dve console of your browser you should post it as an uplate to your question.

Comment: This was a great pick up thank you. It hasn't completely solved the issue I now get a table of <!--template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]}-->

Comment: there are also no console errors... the only thing is Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Web API?  Could it be that you have the same server-side CashMovement model and at the same time you enabled camel casing? You will get as many rows as there are on the server but because there is no clear conversion from server to client your properties might be null. In your ngOnInit try calling `console.log (this.cashmovements)` as the next line so that you can see what is arriving from the server.

Comment: YES you're onto something! that log shows my array coming back.

Comment: Ok, now expand the result and then expand one of the objects to see the names of the properties and their values. If the values of the properties are null (and I bet they are) it could mean that the mapping from server to client wasn't correct. In the article that you linked to your question, notice that properties in his `export interface IWhateverHeCalledIt` are all in lower case letters and yours are in capital. You might have to change those names and reflect the change in your HTML.

Comment: The properties weren't null but it was indeed casing confusing the mapping

Comment: Great stuff! Glad that I was able to help!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me Husein

Comment: Husein do you possibly have advice for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629080/asp-net-core-httpget-single-web-api