# ASP.NET core HttpGet single Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-get, postman

Good Morning,

I’m having difficulty setting up my HTTPGETs and then testing the solution in Postman.

I’m trying to return a single result on both occasions however when I input the parameters nothing loads. So I'm clearly missing something which i need some help on please.

I have 1 parameter {id} in my CashMovementController and if I navigate to localhost/api/cashmovements/{id} it loads however if pass the {id} parameter in postman it fails.

Then in my BondCreditRatingsController I have 2 parameters {ISIN} & {Date} and again I'm not sure how to approach this.

Love to hear some advice/help on this please

Thanks GWS

**Startup.cs**

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

**CashMovementsController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CashMovementsController : Controller
{
    private ICashMovementRepository _cashmovementRepository;

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetCashMovement")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {

        CashMovement _cashmovement = _cashmovementRepository.GetSingle(u => u.CashMovementId == id);

        if (_cashmovement != null)
        {
            CashMovementViewModel _cashmovementVM = Mapper.Map<CashMovement, CashMovementViewModel>(_cashmovement);
            return new OkObjectResult(_cashmovementVM);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

**BondCreditRatingsController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BondCreditRatingsController : Controller
{
    private IBondCreditRatingRepository _bondcreditratingRepository;


    public BondCreditRatingsController(IBondCreditRatingRepository bondcreditratingRepository)
    {
        _bondcreditratingRepository = bondcreditratingRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetBondCreditRating")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id, DateTime efffectivedate)
    {

        BondCreditRating _bondcreditrating = _bondcreditratingRepository.GetSingle(u => u.ISIN == id, u => u.EffectiveDate == efffectivedate);

        if (_bondcreditrating != null)
        {
            BondCreditRatingViewModel _bondcreditratingVM = Mapper.Map<BondCreditRating, BondCreditRatingViewModel>(_bondcreditrating);
            return new OkObjectResult(_bondcreditratingVM);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's error message in Postman? Something about route?

Comment: Hello, I dont have an error in Postman for the 1 parameter {id} however the page is not single its all my data ie http://localhost:5000/api/cashmovements/?id=646 is really just a get all

Comment: have you tried calling it like localhost:5000/api/cashmovements/646? You have a route defined so that should pass the proper parameter.

Comment: Yes i have and that works as expected, will this be overriding Postman?

Comment: @Glenn_Sampson, what do you mean overriding Postman?

Comment: I had expected that when i entered a param {id} and {value} in postman then sent the request a single result would be returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123908/discussion-between-glenn-sampson-and-husein-roncevic).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to map it to api/Controller/method/id you would need to use the code below because you want to map parameter order (no other identifier) to a specific parameter name in the action.

```
[HttpGet("GetCashMovement/{id}")]
```

Your current code should work with below since you are using named parameters and because the request can't be mapped to any other template.

```
/api/CashMovements/GetCashMovement?id=1
```

But that attribute syntax will also (possibly unintentionally) trigger:

```
/api/CashMovements/1
```

Since a sum of your defined template for that action is:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/{id}")]
```

Reason to why /api/ApiTest/GetCashMovement maps GetCashMovement.Get(int i) is because id is defined as optional in startup

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/**{id?}**");
```

> A question mark (?) after the route parameter name defines an optional
>   parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#create-routes